# PHP loop through jquery loop

Tags: php, jquery

I have this simple jQuery function:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var books = {};
    books.id = '1';
    books.author = 'Bob';

    $.post('/index.php',
    {
       books: books
    },
    function(data, textStatus)
    {
       alert(data);  
    });
});
```

And this `index` PHP script:

```
<?php

  foreach($_POST['books'] AS $key) {
       echo ''.$key['id'].' is written by '.$key['author'].'';
  }

?>
```

I want to loop through the jQuery array and display the id and author of each key in the array. I don't know the correct way to access the values in the array. It seems I'm doing it wrong.

Comment: you're passing a single object in `books`, not an array. you should also use `json_decode` in the php to parse the data into an php object

Comment: `var books = [{id:1, author: 'Bob'}, {id:2, author: 'Bill'}]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have misunderstood the difference between `{}` and `[]` in `JavaScript`:

1. `{}` is an object
2. `[]` is an array

In your case you should pass an `array` of book `objects` for this to work in your php script. 
Example:

```
var books = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "The Da Vinci Code",
        author: "Dan Brown"
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "Gray Mountain: A Novel",
        author: "John Grisham"
    }
]
```

To add more elements to the array after it has been initialized, you can simply use `push`:

```
books.push({id: 3, name: "Avatar", author: "Lisa Fitzpatrick"});
```

Will output:

```
1 is written by Dan Brown
2 is written by John Grisham 
3 is written by Lisa Fitzpatrick
```

Comment: hey mate :) How can i push more elements to this array after it has been initiated?